# Não reconhece/encontra as Classes Java no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eu utilizava o Netbeans e não tive nenhum problema. Migrei para o Eclipse a pouco tempo e agora fui fazer um código e o Eclipse não reconhece nem as Classes principais do Java. System, Scanner, etc. O que pode ser? Alguma incompatibilidade  com o JDK?  Alguma configuração no Eclipse que fiz errado? Segue imagem. [image: ex. Classe System não encontrada]

Comment: Já verificou se a JDK tá configurada corretamente no eclipse?

Comment: Muito provavelmente seja a configuração do JDK, olha e retorna pra gente como ta lá.

Comment: Botão direito no projeto > Properties > Tab Libraries; Selecione JRE System Library e clique em editar.
Selecione o Workspace default JRE (Latest version of JRE).
Click Finish and then OK. Avise se funcionar.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves  Aparentemente o problema foi no JRE mesmo, entrei no seguinte menu botão direito no projeto > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries  e a JRE estava desvinculada(unbound) do projeto, alterei e salvei a modificação. Está funcionando normalmente.